# WPF Application Changes From Monitor To Monitor

Tags: c#, wpf, vector-graphics

I am writing a WPF application to be a GUI for a piece of industrial automation.  When run on my development machine with a screen resolution on 1920x1080 it looks a certain way but when I run it on my target machine 1024x768 it changes.  Mostly everything grows.  I thought the idea of Vector based is that stuff should remain the same size.  I have ruled out the computer(Themes settings etc) by plugging the monitor directly into my development machine(It a touch screen monitor).  So its either something Im doing incorrect in my application or the monitor itself

Any ideas??

Edit xaml sample

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Trax_HMI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024" WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized" UseNoneWindowStyle="True" ShowTitleBar="False">
    <Grid >

        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="559" Margin="10,10,-30,-42" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="780" Source="Cell Layout.png"/>

        <Button Content="Log Off" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="542,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="39" Margin="542,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Label x:Name="OPCState" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217"/>
        <Button Content="Reset" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="918,720,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96"/>
     </Grid>
 </Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Answer (score 3):

What happens if you try the following experiment?

1. Run your app with your main window size set to 1920 x 1080.
2. Run your app with your main window size set to 1024 x 576.

When you run with the smaller window size, do your vector graphics look pretty much the same, only smaller, or do they still look different?

If they look pretty much the same, only smaller, that means your graphics are set to stretch and fill their parent container. With a 1920 x 1080 monitor, the aspect ratio is `1920 / 1080 = 1.78`. With a 1024 x 768 monitor, the aspect ratio is `1024 / 768 = 1.33`. (Note that 1024 x 576 has the same aspect ratio as 1920 x 1080.) Since the smaller monitor has a taller aspect ratio, graphics stretched to fill the container will appear taller.

Without seeing your XAML, it's a little difficult to diagnose exactly what's causing the undesired stretching, but since you mention vector graphics, I'm going to assume you're using controls such as `Path`, `Ellipse`, and `Rectangle`. Each of these controls has a `Stretch` property. I recommend you read up on `Stretch` in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I would guess you should be setting `Stretch` to `Uniform` rather than `Fill`, but you will have to experiment to determine exactly what works best.

If you still need help, please post some examples showing your XAML markup.

Comment: Im away from the project at the moment but will try as soon as I have a moment

Answer (score 0):

WPF does not work with actual pixels. Actually it is using DPI settings. Is it possible the DPI settings for the displays are different? Even on the same machine DPI settings are unique per display. If this is the problem [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13858665/296526) might help you further.

Comment: Both displays had the same DPI set as far as I could tell (Windows set to 100%)

Comment: When you attach the monitor as a secondary monitor, and put it 40% to the primary and 60% to the attached monitor, how does it look on the primary? IF it is still a settings issue, this would prove it as the part on the primary monitor would adapt to the settings used for the attached monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I too develop for industrial automation equipment, but in my case I target `1080p` displays but also want a laptop to be able to demo the software at a lower resolution (e.g. `1440x900`).

> When run on my development machine with a screen resolution on 1920x1080 it looks a certain way but when I run it on my target machine 1024x768 it changes. Mostly everything grows.

What you will find is that for Microsoft Windows screen resolutions all [default](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch#Computer_monitor_DPI_standards) to `96dpi` no matter what size the monitor is.  For example I have a 22" monitor running at `1080p`, I can also connect the same PC to my 55" TV at `1080p` also.  Even though the 22" monitor (using a tape measure) would physically fit in a 2x2 grid in the same size as my 55" TV the output bitmap of `1920x1080` for the two displays is exactly the same if I took a screen grab.

So all monitors are `96dpi` which is now starting to cause problems when you have the Retina type displays of `1920x1080` on a 10" tablet, and more frequently the "Make text and other Items larger" settings are available in the display settings to tweak away from the 96dpi to cope with these situations.  WPF applications will scale properly but Win32 apps look a bit fuzzy.

In your case you have `96dpi` for both `1024x768` and `1920x1080` meaning the vector graphics will translate to the same pixels size on both displays.  The difference being that the maximum form size is only `1024x768` on one monitor and `1920x1080` on the other.  If you divide the display using a `Grid` then each column has less pixels on the smaller resolution display meaning any shapes (knowing that the shapes on both monitors will need the same width in pixels) makes a particular shape take more proportion of the column.

#### Three different Solutions

1. On your `1920x1080` development PC then make your WPF application window a fixed size of 1024x768.  Your deployed app will then look exactly like your development machine when it is `Maximised` to full screen

```xaml
  <Window x:Class=" ...
    xmlns=" ....
    Width="1024" Height="768" >
    ....
  </Window>
```

2. Surround all controls with a `Viewbox` and set the `Stretch` attribute to `UniformToFill`.  This will allow your controls to report their size (during the `Measure` phase of the WPF layout process) and then scale uniformly the controls to fit in the available size.

```xaml
  <Window x:Class=" ...
   ....

    <Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill">
       <Grid>
        ....
       </Grid>
    </Viewbox>

  </Window>
```

3. Only scale a proportion of the screen leaving some areas (e.g. text for buttons) rendering at `96dpi`.  You could only enclose parts of the display again with a `Viewbox` or alternatively use the underline function of the `Viewbox` which is available to any control via the `LayoutTransform` dependency property.

```xaml
  <Window x:Class=" ...
     LayoutUpdated="Window_LayoutUpdated" >

   ....

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="60*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="PageScale" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
            </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
            <Rectangle Width="700" Height="700" Fill="Red"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then in the code-behind

```
    private void Window_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((ActualWidth != 0) && (ActualWidth < 1900))
        {
            var scale = ActualWidth / 1920.0;
            PageScale.ScaleX = scale;
            PageScale.ScaleY = scale;
        }
        else
        {
            PageScale.ScaleX = 1.0;
            PageScale.ScaleY = 1.0;
        }
    }
```

Here we have a callback when the windows size has changed (via the handler for `LayoutUpdated` of the `Window` class).  We see if the width of the window is less than the design time window size and scale appropriately the `Canvas` UI element only, leaving the other controls scaling to 100%.  `LayoutTransform` can be used on most WPF UI controls, not just `Canvas`.

Solutions 2 & 3 provide the scaling but they do have some side-effects, namely if you have developed a diagram where a connector line is drawn between two shapes with a width of 1 pixel then this is renders correctly when the scaling is 1:1, but anti-aliasing causes the single pixel line to show solid 1 pixel in some cases but a dithered in others when the scaling is significantly different.  There are advanced options that require lots of research (e.g. `RenderOptions`) and an understanding of the rendering process to eliminate these effects.

Comment: I tried Option 1 as all I care about on the development machine is development but It doesnt seem to produce the results expected  What I get the same smaller application and the rest is blank space.  I posted xaml in the question

Comment: I've not used `MetroWindow` before, so have only run a quick test to see what you are seeing.  A work around for your development system seems to be to add the Min/Max Width&Height to the `MetroWindow` `Xaml` to remove the black.  e.g. `Height="768" Width="1024" WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized" UseNoneWindowStyle="True" ShowTitleBar="False" MinHeight="768" MaxHeight="768" MinWidth="1024" MaxWidth="1024">`