# Wpf-window destroys dpi scaling of non dpi-aware hosting program (vb6)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, com, vb6

my wpf-library gets called from a legacy program(vb6) via COM-Interop. If wpf-windows has been closed the screen of vb6-program resized wrongly and controls look destroyed.
Only in the case, if user has a specific dpi scaling in windows (e.g 125%,150%)

I could handle it by disabling display scaling (..) in compatibility-tab of exe-file like here

[Disable DPI awareness for WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858665/disable-dpi-awareness-for-wpf-application)

(Other solutions like adding a manifestfile, surround window with dpiDecorator
or [assembly: DisableDpiAwareness] in AssemblyInfo.cs didn't work.)

..now vb6-program doesn't look nice anymore. So i need to uncheck that "Disable display scaling.."

How can i achieve, that dpi scaling of my vb6-program doesn't get influenced by a wpf-window?

Comment: How the same issue for wpf overlays controls... Have you solved your issue?

Comment: i made an own exe for that.. so no vb6 integration anymore.