# Have a WPF Application ignore DPI settings

Tags: c#, wpf, dpi

I have a wpf application that is designed for a 1900x1200 resolution but some of our users have used the windows display settings to resize everything by 125%-150%, is there a way to have an application ignore those settings and still display normally?

I have seen something called SetProcessDPIAware [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but havent had any luck with it.

Here is a screen shot of the application with the display scaling turned up to 150%
[image: Application with Scaling]

As you can see the application is way too small and there is no way to get it to be correctly sized.

Comment: You can completely disable dpi scaling in WPF by following [disable-dpi-awareness-for-wpf-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858665/disable-dpi-awareness-for-wpf-application/44171474#44171474)

Comment: You can disable dpi scaling for WPF in .net 4.5 following [disable-dpi-awareness-for-wpf-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858665/disable-dpi-awareness-for-wpf-application/44171474#44171474)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dpi awareness will not help in this case. It will only change CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice matrix, but controls sizes will not change.

I use view box to scale all content. All sizes in my app are designed for Surface Pro 3 portrait:

```
<Window>
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Grid Width="1440" Height="2160">
            <!-- ... -->
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

You can calculate view box size basing on screen DPI. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12414433/991267

Comment: Thanks man. You cured my headache, after a full day looking at per-monitor dpi-awareness.

Answer (score 2):

New way to ignore dpi is:

Right click on your project

Add > New item

Find "Application Manifest File (Windows Only)

Uncomment at line 55, or find  dpiAware

```
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
      <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```