# Microsoft Surface & WPF

Tags: wpf, windows-8, screen-resolution, windows

I have WPF application work with `1024x768` screen resolution, now I want to run this application on Microsoft Surface with wide resolution, I had make new windows with resolution `1366x768`, but unfortunately I can't make it work fine on Surface, I tested it on my laptop, it's work 100%, but I don't understand why it would't work in the same way on Surface.

If there is anyone that has experience with Surface can you please help?

### Update

When I run the WPF windows with resolution `1920x1080` work full screen on my laptop, but the problem is when run application on Surface with the same resolution don't fit the full screen, see this screenshot to more clarity:

[image]

Comment: What does mean, not working ?

Comment: functionality work, but it's not run fully screen on 1366x768 resolution, some parts of window not appear, hope this clear

Comment: The Surface resolution is 1366x720 according to Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Surface

Comment: Surface Pro has a 1920x1080

Comment: It is but that isn't what you asked. You need to be a lot more specific in your question.

Comment: "Can't make it work fine" doesn't give us any idea of what the problem is. What did you expect it to do, and what did it do instead? Why do you think the problem has anything to do with the Surface Pro, rather than being a simple screen-resolution issue?

Comment: I just update my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your surface and laptop have different DPI settings. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412092/wpf-for-lcd-screen-full-hd) how to handle that problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the information provided it may be that your WPF window layout doesn't sufficiently take into account differences in Display text and item sizing on different devices.

On both your Surface Pro and your laptop:

1. Select "Screen Resolution" from the Desktop context menu.
2. Select "Make text and other items larger or smaller" from the Screen
   Resolution window.
3. Check the position of the "Change the size of all items" slider.

By default the Surface Pro is set to Larger. A new Windows 8 install will be set to Smaller.

Comment: The slider from (3) sets the DPI.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF you should not be setting a constant window size, instead you should:

1. Make the window's content react to the window size by using auto sizes and grids instead of constant sizes and panels
2. You can use `WindowState="Maximized"` to make the window full screen

*You can prevent your window from being reduced too much with minwidth and minheight.*